# Android convert String to byte[] - take byte[] on pieces

Tags: android, string, arrays

I have a little question. How can I get `byte array` in pieces and save it as `String`. I mean if y byte array is too big how can I create a few strings from it. As an example, first time I get only the 50 bits/chars of byte, the second time the next 50 and etc.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Use `String.getBytes()` method.

Comment: But what I should do if my byte[] is too big and it's throwin me an outofmemoryexception when I'm trying to create string from it?

Comment: @Bombastic Use String.substring(beginIndex,endIndex).getBytes()

Comment: Actually I think that for converting specific part of string to byte[]. I need the opposite of that. Get maybe first 200 chars in bye[] and concert them as string.

Comment: @Bombastic - You can use the constructor of String class. http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have to create a string, you require several times more memory than size of all bytes.

Firstly, string is a character array, the character has size 2 bytes.

Secondly, the String is an immutable object, so it's impossible to create it using an existing array, so to construct it the second copy of the character array will be created. If memory consumption is vital, consider using `CharSequence` instead of `String`.

Finally, use `StringBuilder` or `StringWriter`, e.g.:

```
String writer = new StringWriter();
writer.write(new String(byteArrayChunk1, "UTF-8"));
...
writer.write(new String(byteArrayChunkN, "UTF-8"));
String resultString = writer.toString();
```

*UPDATE*:
Another option, much more better, I think:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
baos.write(byteArrayChunk1);
baos.write(byteArrayChunkN);
String resultString = baos.toString("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

convert your byte array to Base64 string an then split it. after that in merge phase merge that strings then convert result to Base64.
Or if you have memory limitations first split your byte array to some byte arrays

```
byte[] origBytes = ...;
//a loop for splitting bytes
byte[] splittedBytes1 = ...;
byte[] splittedBytes2 = ...;
...
String strbytes1 = Base64.encodeBytes(splittedBytes1);
String strbytes2 = Base64.encodeBytes(splittedBytes2);
...
```

Comment: I don't see `Base64.encodeBytes(String)` method. Am I missing something?